# Create group label for chunks of rows using data.table

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

I have something like the following dataset:

```
myDT <- structure(list(domain = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), id = 2:22, L1 = 2:22), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

and I would like to create a new column `L2` that creates an index for every 2 rows **within** `domain`. However, if there is a remainder, like in the case for `domain=2` and `id=8,9,10`, then those `id`s should be indexed together as long as its within the same `domain`. Please note that the specific `id` values in the toy dataset are made up and not always consecutive as shown. The output would be:

```
  structure(list(domain = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), id = 2:22, L1 = 2:22, L2=c(1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,4L,4L,4L,
                                                                                                        5L,5L,6L,6L,7L,7L,8L,8L,9L,9L,10L,10L)), 
            row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in data.table?

I've tried playing with `.N`/`rowid` and the integer division operator `%/%` (since every *n* rows should give the same value) inside the subset call but it got me nowhere. For example, I tried something like:

```
myDT[, L2 := rowid(domain)%/%2]
```

but clearly this doesn't address the requirements that the last 3 rows within in `domain=2` have the same index and that the index should continue incrementing for `domain=3`.

**EDIT** Please see revised desired output data table and corresponding description.

**EDIT 2**

Here is an appended version of `myDT`:

```
myDT2 <- structure(list(domain = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), id = 2:40, 
    L1 = 2:40), row.names = c(NA, -39L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

When I ran @chinsoon12's code on the above, I get:

```
structure(list(domain = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), id = 2:40, 
    L1 = 2:40, L2 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
    17L, 18L, 18L)), row.names = c(NA, -39L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

There appears to be 4 values of `L2=11`, when two of them should be 12 because they are in a different domain.

Comment: do you need to generalize to diff window size other than 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea is to make a custom function that will create sequential vectors based on the length of each group and the remainder of that length when divided by two. The function is,

```
f1 <- function(x) {
    v1 <- length(x)
    i1 <- rep(seq(floor(v1 / 2)), each = 2)
    i2 <- c(i1, rep(max(i1), v1 %% 2))
    i2 + seq_along(i2)
}
```

I tried to apply it via `data.table` but I was getting an error about a bug so here it is with base R,

```
cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(with(myDT2, ave(id, domain, FUN = f1))) != 1))
#[1]  1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4  4  5  5  6  6  7  7  8  8  9  9 10 10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 17 18 18 19 19
```

Comment: The (non)base R codes also seem to give the same issue as @chinsoon12's code when I expand the toy dataset with some additional observations - please see edit 2.

Comment: Interesting. This happens because there is a group with length = 2

Comment: @stats134711 edited again. Please check it out now and let me know. Note that I changed both `f1` function and the way I apply it

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option for variable number of repeats other than 2:

```
n <- 4
setDT(myDT)[, L2 := 
        myDT[, {
            x <- ceiling(seq_along(id)/n)
            if (sum(x==x[.N]) < n) x[x==x[.N]] <- floor(.N/n)
            x
        }, domain][, rleid(domain, V1)]
    ]
```

Or a recursive approach:

```
n <- 4
s <- 0
setDT(myDT)[, L2 := 
        myDT[, {
            x <- s + ceiling(seq_along(id)/n)
            if (sum(x==x[.N]) < n) x[x==x[.N]] <- s + floor(.N/n)
            s <- if (s<max(x)) max(x) else s + 1
            x
        }, domain]$V1
    ]
```

output for `n=2`:

```
    domain id L1 L2
 1:      2  2  2  1
 2:      2  3  3  1
 3:      2  4  4  2
 4:      2  5  5  2
 5:      2  6  6  3
 6:      2  7  7  3
 7:      2  8  8  4
 8:      2  9  9  4
 9:      2 10 10  4
10:      3 11 11  5
11:      3 12 12  5
12:      3 13 13  6
13:      3 14 14  6
14:      3 15 15  7
15:      3 16 16  7
16:      3 17 17  8
17:      3 18 18  8
18:      3 19 19  9
19:      3 20 20  9
20:      3 21 21 10
21:      3 22 22 10
22:      4 23 23 11
23:      4 24 24 11
24:      5 25 25 12
25:      5 26 26 12
26:      5 27 27 13
27:      5 28 28 13
28:      5 29 29 14
29:      5 30 30 14
30:      5 31 31 15
31:      5 32 32 15
32:      5 33 33 16
33:      5 34 34 16
34:      5 35 35 17
35:      5 36 36 17
36:      5 37 37 18
37:      5 38 38 18
38:      5 39 39 19
39:      5 40 40 19
    domain id L1 L2
```

output for `n=4`:

```
    domain id L1 L2
 1:      2  2  2  1
 2:      2  3  3  1
 3:      2  4  4  1
 4:      2  5  5  1
 5:      2  6  6  2
 6:      2  7  7  2
 7:      2  8  8  2
 8:      2  9  9  2
 9:      2 10 10  2
10:      3 11 11  3
11:      3 12 12  3
12:      3 13 13  3
13:      3 14 14  3
14:      3 15 15  4
15:      3 16 16  4
16:      3 17 17  4
17:      3 18 18  4
18:      3 19 19  5
19:      3 20 20  5
20:      3 21 21  5
21:      3 22 22  5
22:      4 23 23  6
23:      4 24 24  6
24:      5 25 25  7
25:      5 26 26  7
26:      5 27 27  7
27:      5 28 28  7
28:      5 29 29  8
29:      5 30 30  8
30:      5 31 31  8
31:      5 32 32  8
32:      5 33 33  9
33:      5 34 34  9
34:      5 35 35  9
35:      5 36 36  9
36:      5 37 37 10
37:      5 38 38 10
38:      5 39 39 10
39:      5 40 40 10
    domain id L1 L2
```

Comment: @JorisChau, why dont you add `rleid` to your code and i delete this.

Comment: @chinsoon12, it seems to be giving me weird behavior when I add some more observations to the current data table (see edit 2 above).

Comment: @stats134711 have u changed the data in edit 2? i do not see any diff

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach updated for the edited question (inspired by @Sotos use of `cumsum`):

1. For each `domain` id, create a repeated sequence `1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...`, setting the final sequence element to zero by default.
2. Take the `cumsum` over the created sequence across `domain` id's.

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(myDT2)

myDT2[, L2 := c(head(rep_len(c(1, 0), .N), -1), 0), by = domain][, L2 := cumsum(L2)][]
#>     domain id L1 L2
#>  1:      2  2  2  1
#>  2:      2  3  3  1
#>  3:      2  4  4  2
#>  4:      2  5  5  2
#>  5:      2  6  6  3
#>  6:      2  7  7  3
#>  7:      2  8  8  4
#>  8:      2  9  9  4
#>  9:      2 10 10  4
#> 10:      3 11 11  5
#> 11:      3 12 12  5
#> 12:      3 13 13  6
#> 13:      3 14 14  6
#> 14:      3 15 15  7
#> 15:      3 16 16  7
#> 16:      3 17 17  8
#> 17:      3 18 18  8
#> 18:      3 19 19  9
#> 19:      3 20 20  9
#> 20:      3 21 21 10
#> 21:      3 22 22 10
#> 22:      4 23 23 11
#> 23:      4 24 24 11
#> 24:      5 25 25 12
#> 25:      5 26 26 12
#> 26:      5 27 27 13
#> 27:      5 28 28 13
#> 28:      5 29 29 14
#> 29:      5 30 30 14
#> 30:      5 31 31 15
#> 31:      5 32 32 15
#> 32:      5 33 33 16
#> 33:      5 34 34 16
#> 34:      5 35 35 17
#> 35:      5 36 36 17
#> 36:      5 37 37 18
#> 37:      5 38 38 18
#> 38:      5 39 39 19
#> 39:      5 40 40 19
#>     domain id L1 L2
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I must have edited my post while you were trying out the code. The revised output doesn't have the index restarting with each new `domain` value. Also this code seems to give me an error: `Type of RHS ('double') must match LHS ('integer').`